# Amazon Virtual Private Cloud - Can I use a normal VPN Connection

Tags: vpn, cloud, amazon-vpc

I want to use amazon VPC so that I can connect directly to cloud-based databases and application servers over a secure VPN connection.

From the description on Amazon's site it appears to require a "customer gateway" - some kind of permanent VPN router on my side.

Is there any way I can just connect to VPC from my home computer using a standard VPN connection using CISCO VPN Manager or Shrew Soft VPN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular VPN connection to your Amazon VPC instances, they do recommend a VPN router if you want to give permanent access to it from your office or preferred location of course, but we're developing on it just with regular one to one VPN connections without any kind of issue.

Comment: If you can point me in the direction of some guidance on how to achieve this you get the 'tick' :-)

Comment: Here's a small guide (that I followed) on how to setup this in racoon on Linux, you can also use any kind of IPSEC client to connect there (plenty available both for mac and windows as well) http://openfoo.org/blog/amazon_vpc_with_linux.html

Comment: Why is this stuff so hard?!  Man that's some guide!  Think I'll need to hire a freelancer to set this up for me.

Comment: IPSEC is a bit of a pain but so secure... you feel really really secure, because if somebody takes the time to configure that, they must really want it ;) </joke>